# Java StringTokenizer only reading first line

Tags: java, arrays, loops, stringtokenizer, inputstreamreader

My problem is that `StringTokenizer` seems to only read the first line of ip.txt

What I'm trying to do is load a list of IP addresses from "ip.txt" and save it into an array to automatically ping devices on my network to see if their online. No matter what I try I can't get more than the first line in "ip.txt" into the array. My delimiter is "//" and the name of the ip address is also stored in the `txt` file. I included the code and a sample of the text file.

Thanks in advance!!

```
public class IP {
    public static IP[] ips = new IP[100];
    public static int total_ips=0;

    String name;
    String ip1;
    String ip2;
    String ip3;
    String ip4;
    String fullIP;

    public static void read_ips() throws FileNotFoundException{

        FileInputStream fstream1 = new FileInputStream("ip.txt");

        String line;
        String delimiter = "//";

        StringTokenizer tokenizer;
        BufferedReader input = null;     
        try {
            int i = 0;
            int totalIps = 0;

            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream1));
            line = input.readLine();

            //outer while
            while(line != null) {
            tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, delimiter);

            while(tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {//process tokens in line
                ips[i] = new IP();
                ips[i].name = tokenizer.nextToken();
                ips[i].ip1 = tokenizer.nextToken();
                ips[i].ip2 = tokenizer.nextToken();
                ips[i].ip3 = tokenizer.nextToken();
                ips[i].ip4 = tokenizer.nextToken();
                ips[i].fullIP = ips[i].ip1+"."+ips[i].ip2+"."+ips[i].ip3+"."+ips[i].ip4;
                i++;
                totalIps = i;

                System.out.println(line);
            }   
            line = input.readLine(); //next line
            }//close outer while
            total_ips = totalIps; // count of total cars
            System.out.println("total_ips after i++ "+total_ips);
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to open file " + fstream1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to read from file " + fstream1);
            }finally {
                // Close the file
                try {
             if (input != null)
                 input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to close file " + fstream1);
                }
            }   
    }
}
```

And here is an example of ip.txt

```
Desktop1//192//168//1//127//
Desktop2//192//168//1//128//
Desktop3//192//168//1//129//
```

Comment: Just a reminder of what the Javadocs say about StringTokenizer. "... _StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead._ ..."

Comment: I tried running your code on my machine and it's working fine. It's reading whole of ip.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be working fine. The more classic approach to iterate over the BufferedReader one line at a time is by using an expression like:

```
while ( (line = input.readLine()) != null) {.
```

That's about the only refactoring I did to your code and it is working. You may want to print the fullIP in order to check that you are correctly retrieving it.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class IP {
    public static IP[] ips = new IP[100];
    public static int total_ips=0;

    String name;
    String ip1;
    String ip2;
    String ip3;
    String ip4;
    String fullIP;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        read_ips();
    }
    public static void read_ips() throws FileNotFoundException{

        FileInputStream fstream1 = new FileInputStream("c:\\ips\\ip.txt");

        String line;
        String delimiter = "//";

        StringTokenizer tokenizer;
        BufferedReader input = null;     
        try {
            int i = 0;
            int totalIps = 0;

            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream1));
            while ( (line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, delimiter);

                while(tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {//process tokens in line
                    ips[i] = new IP();
                    ips[i].name = tokenizer.nextToken();
                    ips[i].ip1 = tokenizer.nextToken();
                    ips[i].ip2 = tokenizer.nextToken();
                    ips[i].ip3 = tokenizer.nextToken();
                    ips[i].ip4 = tokenizer.nextToken();
                    ips[i].fullIP = ips[i].ip1+"."+ips[i].ip2+"."+ips[i].ip3+"."+ips[i].ip4;
                    System.out.println(ips[i].fullIP);
                    i++;
                    totalIps = i;

                    System.out.println(line);
                }   
            }


            total_ips = totalIps; // count of total cars
            System.out.println("total_ips after i++ "+total_ips);
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to open file " + fstream1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to read from file " + fstream1);
            }finally {
                // Close the file
                try {
             if (input != null)
                 input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to close file " + fstream1);
                }
            }   
    }
}
```

**And an illustration:**

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what went wrong with my code but I assume it was a problem with eclipse because it worked after rebooting my machine, that's probably a hint that I should be using the split method instead. I also changed my code as you recommended. Thanks!